# Conditional Delete in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to piece together code to make my macro work correctly. This approach has served me well in the past but I cannot seem to adapt any code correctly.

I found the following

```
Sub way()

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If Len(Cell) < 2 Then Cell.EntireRow.Delete
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I can adapt the If Len(Cell) criteria to my liking. For example = 10

I do not know how to adapt the code to make it search through all cells in column A and delete the appropriate rows. The code above only does it for A1.

Ideally I would like to delete all rows with cells in column A that have a length of 10 characters. Or alternatively, with a completely different set of code, delete all other rows that do not contain cells in column A that have a length of 10 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deleting rows it is best to loop backwards:

```
Sub way()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long


Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    If Len(ws.Cells(i, 1)) < 2 Then ws.Rows(i).Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, your loop is going through every cell in the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) radiating out from A1. Your narrative expresses that you only want to examine column A but delete the [Range.EntireRow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx).

The For .. Next loop stepping backwards proposed by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) is likely your best bet but if you are more comfortable with a For ... Each In loop then yours can be adjusted.

```
Sub way()
    Dim cl As Range, dels As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cl In .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
            If Len(cl.Value2) = 10 Then
                If Not dels Is Nothing Then
                    Set dels = Union(dels, cl)
                Else
                    Set dels = cl
                End If
            End If
        Next cl
    End With

    If Not dels Is Nothing Then _
        dels.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

The logic to delete rows that did not have a value in column A that was 10 characters, symbols or digits long would be `If Len(cl.Value2) <> 10 Then`.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't checked for syntax, but something like this should work:

```
dim idx as integer
idx = 1
while Range("A" + cstr(idx)).value <> ""
    'insert your delete logic here...
idx = idx + 1
wend
```